# Change value of decorator parameter variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have the following code where default "User" value is None and it is taken by the decorator "need_authentication", the case is that I change the User value but when I call the decorator it always gets None. I now the User variable is not "None" because I print it before calling show_content
This is my code:

```
import user

User = None

def login():
    #In this function, I change User value


@user.need_authentication(actual_user=User)
def show_content():
    print('contenido')

login()
show_content():
    print("content")
```

this is my decorator:

```
def need_authentication(actual_user = None):
    def decorator(func):
        def check_authentication(*args, **kwargs):
            print(app.User)
            print(user)
            if user == None:
                print("lo siento, necesita registrarse para acceder al contenido")
            else:
                func(*args, **kwargs)

        return check_authentication

    return decorator
```

Comment: Default values for function parameters are evaluated when the function is defined, not when the function is called.

Comment: Where do you use `actual_user` in the decorator?

Comment: And when you use a decorator, you're calling the decorator function at the time that you define the function. It creates the decorated function using the value of `User` at that time, it doesn't defer it to when the function is called.

Comment: If you need to reference something dynamic, the parameter should be a global object, whose state can be changed dynamically. See the section **Class Based Decorators** here: http://scottlobdell.me/2015/04/decorators-arguments-python/

Answer (score 0):

you could use a dict:

```
actual_user = {'user': None}

def need_authentication(actual_user = actual_user):
    def decorator(func):
        def check_authentication(*args, **kwargs):
            print(app.User)
            user = actual_user[user]
            print(user)
            if user == None:
                print("lo siento, necesita registrarse para acceder al contenido")
            else:
                func(*args, **kwargs)

        return check_authentication

    return decorator
```